# String variable as literal bytes

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm reading in a config file. Say I end up with a configuration variable:

```
header = '\x42\x5a\x68'
```

I want to match this against binary files using startswith.

Unsurprisingly, I get a `"TypeError startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str"`, if I try to use this directly. How do I use this string? I don't want it encoded.

I have to read the string from a file. If there's some other way to go about this, I'm all ears. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example code that produces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I use this string? I don't want it encoded.

You must. Make a decision, either `decode` the string you get from the binary file or `encode` the `header` name. You can't mix those two types together.

See *[Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bit](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)* in the python docs, all mixing between these types (as it occurs in `startswith` too) will result in a `TypeError`.